# Rails 3.2.11 asset precompile fails if threadsafe! enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thread-safety, assets, eager-loading, precompile

I'm on Rails 3.2.11 and ruby 1.9.3.125

My app is working ok in devel and production if threadsafe! off

With threadsafe! enabled I get an error during precompiling, in my asset
assetsolutions.js.erb (which is the main js file of the application) I use the
Workorder class as in the next line
if ($('#workorder_worktype').val()=='<%= Workorder::REPAIR %>')

with threadsafe! the class can't be found at precompile time, I've done some reasearch and I think it may be related with rails switching off eager loading if threadsafe! is on

How can I include the Workorder class to make precompile work?

error follows:

c:/rails3/ruby/bin/ruby.exe c:/rails3/Ruby/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_
ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant #::Workorder
  (in C:/rails3/applications/assetsolutions/app/assets/javascripts/preloaded/ass
etsolution.js.erb)
C:/rails3/applications/assetsolutions/app/assets/javascripts/preloaded/assetsolu
tion.js.erb:763:in `evaluate_source'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [c:/rails3/ruby/bin/ruby.exe c:/rails3/Ruby...]

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Tnx
Fabio

Comment: Just check ur browser console when You are in development env... and Most probably there is an error in any js file.

Comment: hum... no, in devel I can see no error... and all works as expected... but even in production, if I don't active threadsafe! Addendum: I have used a workaround to replace the calls to Workorder in the .js and now I'm able to precompile, but it seems to me that the app still uses only one thread, because if I start a long operation on a tab and then try to use another tab to use the application it is freezed, while in 2.3.8 it is not... any ideas?

Comment: P.S. same behaviour with puma and thin --threaded

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue on a Rails 3.2.13 application and I solved it by adding `config.eager_load = true` to my `config/environments/production.rb` file. This also solved eager loading issues I had with rake not loading models.