# Rails seed file not loading for me in production profile after 3.16 and capistrano 3.1 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sqlite

I have an app that I have been in happily developing for some time, and haven't had any trouble  seeding the production database with my seed file until recently, as I have been attempting to get capistrano deployment working, which spawned an upgrade and gem dependency exercise;-first I blamed capistrano but this behavior happens locally.

So if I reset and seed with:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:reset
```

and I end up with tables being undefined that the seed file is attempting to load: e.g:

...tables being built:
.
.
.
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0037s
-- assume_migrated_upto_version(20140117153600, ["/Users/jaytho/Projects/1.1.1-a1.dev.merge_test/db/migrate"])
   -> 0.0020s
BankCards
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant BankCard
/Users/jaytho/Projects/1.1.1-a1.dev.merge_test/db/seeds.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

/Users/jaytho/Projects/1.1.1-a1.dev.merge_test/db/seeds.rb:6:in`block in '
/Users/jaytho/Projects/1.1.1-a1.dev.merge_test/db/seeds.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/engine.rb:525:in`load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/engine.rb:525:in `load_seed'

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:347:in`block (2 levels) in '
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:290:in `block (2 levels) in '
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with –trace)

of which BankCard is the first table seeds.rb is attempting to populate. Comment out BankCard and it just goes to the next table.

The db:reset command works perfectly with in the other environments:

```
RAILS_ENV=development rake db:reset
```

and

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:reset
```

a downgrade to 3.2.15 did not help.  I also attempted many permutations like:

```
bundle exec rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=production
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed
```

and I even wiped all my migrations and tried just from the schema thinking that a mangled migration silently causing an issue:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:schema:load db:seed
```

without any luck- exact same answer.

I also attempted to extract the seed.rb routines into a separate rake task- same result.

The brain twister for me is that if I call the seeds.rb from the console:

```
'echo load “db/seeds.rb”' | RAILS_ENV=production rails c
```

she loads without any issues.  It works from the console.

I attempted to get into databases.rake and try and recreate the environment there to duplicate the environment into my own rakefile; however, since calls into databases.rake exhibit the same problem, I am pretty much stuck between a rock and a hard place.

What can I be doing wrong to pollute only the production environment? How can I debug this?

Thanks in advance.  Beer is on me if you ever are in Dallas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some insomnia and some more varied google searches I stumbled on this website: http://community.activestate.com/node/9065 and 
[Rails 3.2.11 asset precompile fails if threadsafe! enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430457/rails-3-2-11-asset-precompile-fails-if-threadsafe-enabled) where they give clues that threadsafe is important.

Sure enough; if I comment out the threadsafe line in config/environments/production.rb:

```
  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!
```

My rake db:seed tasks work in production.

the solutions in those articles, for some reason didn't work.  I ended up doing this to fix it in config/environments/production.rb

```
 # Enable threaded mode
 config.threadsafe!  unless $rails_rake_task
```

I hope this helps somebody else out who is upgrading.